# Why R stores my training and test labels under Data as tibbles?

Tags: dataframe, tibble, coercion

R now stores my training and test labels under Data as tibbles whereas before they were stored under Values, why is this happening?

```
wbcd = wisc_bc_data_1_

wbcd <- wbcd[-1]

wbcd$diagnosis <- factor(wbcd$diagnosis, levels = c("B", "M"), labels = c("Benign", "Malignant"))

normalize <- function(x) { return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}

wbcd_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(wbcd[2:31], normalize))

wbcd_train <- wbcd_n[1:469, ] wbcd_test <- wbcd_n[470:569, ]

wbcd_train_labels <- wbcd[1:469, 1] wbcd_test_labels <- wbcd[470:569, 1]

wbcd_test_pred <- knn(train = wbcd_train, test = wbcd_test, cl = wbcd_train_labels, k=21)
```

**Error in knn(train = wbcd_train, test = wbcd_test, cl = wbcd_train_labels, : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths**

When I have done this previously the wbcd_train_labels were saving under Values in my global environment and now it is saving as Data, why has it now changed?